# Passing values from a div containing list from another page

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I am trying to pass values using 'post' from three drop down lists to the database using php script where I insert values into the database with values of the three lists

previously I retrieved a list from another page into a div time.php using jquery ajax call

code for which looks like this :-

```
//This script uses jquery and ajax it is used to set the values in
// the time field whenever a day is selected.
$(document).ready(function(){                               
    $("#day").change(function(){                

          var day=$("#day").val();
          var doctor=$("#doctor").val();

          $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url:"time.php",
              data:"day="+day+"&doctor="+doctor,
              success:function(data){
                 $("#time").html(data);
                 }

          });

    });
});
```

code for the html section looks something like this:-

```
<select id="doctor">some options</select>
<select id="day">some options</select>
<div id="time"> </div>
```

Now the values from the two lists are going through fine. But the one I retrieved into the div is not going through. Could you point me in the right direction? 
Thanks in advance.

```
   //The php script for insertion

    <?php
session_start();                  //Use this to include session variables
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","clinic","myclinic","myclinic");
    // Check connection

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO appointment(username, doctor, day, time) VALUES('$_SESSION[username]', '$_POST[doctor]', '$_POST[day]', '$_POST[time]')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }


    mysqli_close($con);
    header("location:login_success.php");
         ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrive div content like input, select etc

You have to get it like

```
var time = $("#time").html();
```

Your code will be

Add a button to your page

```
<input type='button' value='Send' id='send'>
```

Then add

```
$(document).ready(function(){                               
    $("#send").click(function(){                

          var day=$("#day").val();
          var doctor=$("#doctor").val();
          var time = $("#time").find("select").val();

          $.ajax({
              type:"post",
              url:"time.php",
              data:"day="+day+"&doctor="+doctor+"&time="+time, //add param
              success:function(data){

                 }

          });

    });
});
```

Comment: Please send your html form, it will work only on change day dropdown list. After showing your form you will get answer

Comment: I am using HttpFox it still says just doctor and day are being passed to insert.php

Comment: Right so basically what you're saying is I should have two scripts in  my code one to retrieve values in div and this to post values using ajax on click event.

Comment: Okay so I fiddled around a little bit. I found out that ('#time').text() on a div returns a string of all the options in the drop down list. I want is just one value from the list, the one which is selected

Comment: Answer editted try now. line modified to var time = $("#time").find("select").val();